# How to return the hyperlink of text by google scripts in google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a google scripts in my google sheets.

## Input:

```
a number # means the question number.
(or can be a number with a simple function)
```

## Output:

```
a hyperlink in same cell, the origin number with the hyperlink of 
"https://www.lintcode.com/problem/${input number}/".
```

## Example:

### 1. input the number "123" into the cell

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hnHV.jpg

### 2. When I press Enter, I want it to return the origin number with hyperlink ("url/${input_number}/")

https://i.stack.imgur.com/edDB1.jpg

### I have already tried the following google scripts.

```
function insertLink(input) {
  var text = `${input}`;
  var url = `https://www.lintcode.com/problem/${input}/`
  var value = `=HYPERLINK("${url}", "${text}")`;

  return value;
}
```

If I input

```
=insertlink(123)
```

But it returns like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tliCt.jpg

If I paste this result (only value) to another cell, it will show the result I want.

paste this:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://www.lintcode.com/problem/123/", "123")
```

then it will show the result I want.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/edDB1.jpg

I want the script can return directly and I don't need to paste it to another cell again.
Are there any methods to do this? (methods without a sample function will be best!)

Comment: Since my reputation is not enough, so I can't directly post the images. I use imgur url instead.

Answer (score 0):

#### Creating a hyperlink

```
function insertLink(input="lintcode") {
  Logger.log(`=HYPERLINK("https://www.lintcode.com/problem/${input}/","${input}")`)
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").setValue(`=HYPERLINK("https://www.lintcode.com/problem/${input}/","${input}")`);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A2").setFormula(`=HYPERLINK("https://www.lintcode.com/problem/${input}/","${input}")`);
}
Execution log
12:32:25 PM Notice  Execution started
12:32:25 PM Info    =HYPERLINK("https://www.lintcode.com/problem/google/","google")
12:32:26 PM Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: I want the function can return the string to the google sheet, not just show in the console log.